# 2011 Toyota Sequoia - intermittent higher engine RPMs and faint squeaking

Tags: engine, toyota, noise, squeaking, sequoia

The vehicle had been idling with the engine running for about 25 min (with A/C going on a hot day), and after driving off and going about 50mph and the engine revolutions sounded higher than usual and there was a faint squeaking (too quiet to record on video).

- This continued for a couple minutes and then stopped on its own, possibly (but not sure) related to dropping down in speed to 25-35mph before going back up
- It is an automatic and was not in a gear other than drive, and changing to manual shifting and going up and down gears did not solve it either

What's odd is the squeaking was after the engine was running for a while as opposed to when cold, yet also going away later.

From researching online, the top theory would be the fan clutch - any thoughts?

Comment: Does it only happen when the A/C has been running? Could be a fan, could be the compressor, a pulley, the water pump, or none of the above. Next time it happens, pop the hood and carefully try and listen around the serpentine belt. Try turning off the AC and see if it stops once the compressor clutch disengages.

Answer (score 0):

Serpentine belt and A/C drive belt tensioner replacement seems to have resolved the issue.

Credit @Z4-tier's comment